# Include ImageMagick headers file in catkin pakage

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to include the header files of ImageMagick in my catkin package.

I am using include_directories() function in CMakeLists.text file.
like this :

find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS magick)
include_directories(include ${ImageMagick_INCLUDES} )

still its giving the error no such file or directory.

What to do to resolve this??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150041/include-imagemagick-headers-file-in-catkin-pakage/) by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-08**:
First of all if you don't use the "REQUIRED" keyword you can't even be sure that the package has been found. And second you should output the content of the variable ImageMagick_INCLUDES to check what it actually contains. It might just be empty because either the package was not found or the variable name is actually wrong and should be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm whether a catkin expert nor have I ever used ImageMagick but after a short search I found [this CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-ros-interface/blob/hydro-devel/sr_movements/CMakeLists.txt).

They do

```
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++ REQUIRED)
```

This might help you.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on 2014-04-07**:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):

**Could NOT find ImageMagick (missing: ImageMagick_Magick++_LIBRARY)


 (found  version "6.7.7-10")**